# Use KeyPress event logic for Textbox.Text assignment

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have the below code on the KeyPress event of a textbox howver a need has now come in meaning I have to do myTextbox.Text = "A input string"

```
 Private Sub ChequeAmountKeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtChequeAmount.KeyPress

        Dim tb As TextBox = sender

        If (e.KeyChar = "." AndAlso tb.Text.Length = 0) Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If

        If Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Or (e.KeyChar = "." And tb.Text.IndexOf(".") < 0)) Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If

        If (tb.SelectionStart > tb.Text.Length - 2 And tb.Text.IndexOf(".") >= 0 And tb.Text.IndexOf(".") + 3 = tb.Text.Length) Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If



        If (tb.Text.IndexOf(".") < 0 And tb.Text.Length >= 4 And e.KeyChar <> ".") Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If

        If (tb.Text.IndexOf(".") >= 0 And tb.Text.Length >= 7) Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If


        If (e.KeyChar = ControlChars.Back) Then
            e.Handled = False
        End If


    End Sub
```

This input string could contain a format that I do not want and whilst the keypress event caters for the need when the user is typing I need to handle it in the case of a text assignment.

I thought firing the keypress event after I assigned the text property but I dont think that will offer what I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is refactor this code into a method and then call that method from the relevant events.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check each key individually as it is typed and also the assigned string all at once, it will probably be best to use two functions for this, adding one to validity check the string.

I usually prefer to use the Leave event to check the string all at once, because it may be more natural for the user to enter the entire string before it is checked. If you do this, you can call the same validity check function from the Leave event handler and before the text is assigned.